# How to fix pastespecial error in Excel VBA : Run time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code to copy paste data from one workbook to another workbook

I am getting an error "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed " op on clicking debug and F5 the code runs without any issues

And I have used Application.displayalerts = false,but still I am getting the error and code runs if I try to press F5

```
        S_xlobj.Activate
        S_wsObj.Select
        S_wsObj.Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Config").Cells(i, 3) & F1_startRow & ":" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Config").Cells(i, 3) & F1_Lastrow).Copy
        D_xlobj.Activate
        D_wsObj.Select
        D_wsObj.Range(Split(Cells(1, j).Address, "$")(1) & 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I expect it should run without errors. Sometimes it runs without any error but some times I am getting this error

Comment: First of all hiding alerts doesn't solve errors! Secondly avoid using `Select` and specify a worksheet for every `Cells` object! Excel cannot know in which sheet `Cells(1, j).Address` is if you don't specify one. Also please tell what the result of `Debug.Print Cells(1, j).Address` is *after* you specified it's worksheet. • Read and apply  [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: `Range(Split(Cells(1, j).Address, "$")(1) & 2)` is equivalent with `Cells(2, j)`.

Comment: @Peh I have updated the code based on your comments but it ran without errors for the first time and again it started giving errors.And Debug.print Cells(1,j).address is giving a valid address to me

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

1. Excel cannot know in which sheet `Cells(1, j).Address` is. Always specify a sheet!

   ```
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetNAme").Cells(1, j).Address
   'or
   D_wsObj.Cells(1, j).Address
   ```
2. `Range(Split(Cells(1, j).Address, "$")(1) & 2)` is the same as `Cells(2, j)`
3. Don't use `.Select` or `.Activate` it is not needed. [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

So this should work (the rest is not needed):

```
S_wsObj.Range(S_wsObj.Cells(i, 3) & F1_startRow & ":" & S_wsObj.Cells(i, 3) & F1_Lastrow).Copy
D_wsObj.Cells(2, j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 1):

I think repeating the same action multiple times I am getting this error

Rather than using copy/paste, I have used arrays and now it is working without any issues

New code that I am using (for easy reference: removed variables that are dynamically getting column name)

```
Dim myArray() As Variant
myArray = S_wsObj.Range("B6:B600").Value  '''storing the values in array rather than copy
D_wsObj.Range("A2:A560") = myArray    ''' Filling range with the array instead of paste
```

This is working like charm without any issues

Thanks for all your support